# Rails model/form layout question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, has-many

I'm making a recipe-manager (who isn't as their first app?) in Rails, and here is my layout:

```
Ingredient belongs to Recipe
Recipe has many Ingredients
```

What is the best way to make a form that reflects this relationship? I was thinking an input that, when one is filled, creates another, so there is always 'one more' at the end of the form for ingredients.

Once I have the UI made, what would the structure of the model and controller look like? Right now I have the scaffolded  controller `create` method:

```
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to(recipes_path, :notice => 'You made a new recipe!') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @recipe, :status => :created, :location => @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @recipe.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Should the `params[:recipe]` just be a more deeply nested object/hash/dictionary, that contains an array of ingredients or something?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `accepts_nested_attributes` here.

Some links:

> API:
>   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for
>   Screencasts:
>   http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
>   http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

So your model will look like this

```
class Recipie  < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingridients, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Views:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
  ... # reciepe fields
  <%= f.fields_for :ingridients do |i| %>
    ... # your ingridients forms
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And controller

```
def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
  @recipe.save # some save processing
end
```

Comment: Aha, thanks for pointing me towards this. It's hard to find the resources if you're not totally sure what to look for. This looks like it's specifically meant for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add ingredients by comma delimited.

This can be a `text_field_tag` because you will need to parse it and save each word spaced by a comma with a before save.

```
class Recipie  < ActiveRecord::Base 

    has_many :ingredients

    before_save :add_ingredients 

    attr_accessor :ingredients_to_parse #this will be the text_field_tag

    def add_ingredients
        #create an array of ingredients from #ingredients_to_parse
        #then loop through that array i.e. you have your ingredients_array   
        ingredients_array.each do 
            Ingredient.create(:recipe => self, :other_params => 'stuff')
        end
        #there are a lot of ways, I just used create to show you how to add it
    end
end
```

So then in your form just have that `text_field_tag`

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
    <% f.text_field :name %>
    <% text_field_tag :ingredients_to_parse %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then you can add Javascript so that each time a comma is added in that `text_field_tag` you can just use some js to to so fancy stuff.

This way it will work when servers are slow, js is not working well, etc. It's always a good idea to get the HTML version going first too.

Good luck, let me know if you have questions/problems.

Comment: Ah, so your strategy is just to have the user submit one string (which happens to be many ingredients) and then parse it out once it gets server side. Interesting take, I'll think about this and see how it fits into the app's design. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, In terms of HTML is a lot less work; the js however is more work but it's been done before so there are resources out then. Such as Google 'javascript adding tags'. You don't even need ajax at first or at all. let me know if you need help with the js.